# Phonegap 1.9 Cordova webview, what's the difference?

Tags: cordova

Sorry for such a strange question, but i cant seem to find the answer on phonegaps own webpage.

They say that 1.9 includes the cordova webview, which I guess substitutes the native webview.

But what's the main benefit and difference in these webviews?

More speed, native integration or something?

Comment: It is a wrapper around web view, which adds necessary stuffs for Javascript to access native features. At least this is what I see in Cordova 1.8.

Answer (score 7):

The CordovaWebView extends the native WebView and adds the bits that are necessary to make calls into the native layer from JavaScript. Docs on it are forthcoming but to see an example you can look at:

https://github.com/infil00p/CordovaActionView

Answer (score 2):

There are definitely some incompatabilities between cordova webview and phonegap, thought they are said to be of the same origin.

I'm using cordova webview for my webapp, for I just cannot figure out how to use phonegap to wrap an online webapp, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804291/wrap-online-website-into-android-app-using-phonegap).

And as you can see, the documentation on PhoneGap website still references the 1.9.0 version of cordova, thought cordova is already in its 2.7.0 version.

So practically I suggest you treat them separately.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe acquired Phonegap, and changed its name to Cordova. The Cordova Webview allows to display HTML pages, and the phonegap frameworks allows to use devices features using a javascript API (sensors, contacts, camera, etc...)

Comment: Well thats what phonegap does in the first place. What i mean is that now they have added what they call the cordova webviewer from version 1.9.