# Should I Use CordovaWebView or AndroidWebView in my android native App?

Tags: android, cordova

I am making a few simple applications for android platform using Phonegap. I used to use the Android WebView to display the html files  put in the assets directory like this ....

```
public class MyQuiz extends DroidGap
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

Soon.. I came to know that this can be done using Cordova Web View too. Is there any difference between the two? Like Performance, Look & feel or anything else? Is my approach Right ?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some useful links which will help you out to understand the exact difference between AndroidWebView and CordovaWebView

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11297966/2266525
- http://wiki.apache.org/cordova/CordovaWebView
- http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html